# Assigning values of keys using a for loop in a list or array

Tags: python

In python, we can use a for loop to print out keys and values like the following:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
        print(k,v)
```

I understand this. But But i have a hard time understanding the following lines of code.

```
count = [['UNK', -1]]
count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
# made a new dictionary
dictionary = dict()
# Here is where i'm confuse
for word, _ in count:
    dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
```

Does this means that every `word` in the dictionary are keys and the length of the dictionary is the value?

Comment: Note that the length of `dictionary` grows in the `for` loop as items are added to it, so the values assigned to the keys from `count` are 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and that's almost certainly not what was meant, unless it's trying to save the order in which words were added (and, if that's the case, this is a terrible way of doing it).